# MongoDB - How to get the count for a find query

Tags: java, mongodb

I cannot for the life of me find out how to get a count for a find query using the java driver in mongo db. Can someone please put me out of my misery?

I have the following:

```
MongoCursor<Document> findRes = collection.find().iterator();
```

But there is no count method that I can find anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 public Long getTotalCount(String collectionName, Document filterDocument) {
        MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
        return filterDocument != null ? collection.count(filterDocument) : collection.count();
 }
```

Where filterDocument is org.bson.Document with filter criterias or null if you want to get total count

You may also use more powerful `Filters` class. Example:   `collection.count(Filters.and(Filters.eq("field","value"),second condition and so on));`

So, in order to be able to take both Document and Filters as param you may change signature to  `public Long getTotalCount(String collectionName, Bson filterDocument) {`

Answer (score 3):

```
long rows = db.getCollection(myCollection).count(new Document("_id", 10)) ;
```

this is in Java, `myCollection` is collection name.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.count()` is what you're looking for I believe. Your find query returns a `Cursor` so you can just call `count()` on that.

Comment: Its not there. I do not see a count method for the cursor. Im using MongoCursor<Document> findRes. Then when I do the find I use collection.find().iterator(). But there is no count method on that

Comment: Build your query and pass it to the `find()` on your collection. That returns a `DBCursor` which should have a `count()` on it (at least it did last time I checked).

Comment: It seems to have changed in the latest version. Now you create your query and pass it to a count. So instead of collection.find(<query>), its collection.count(<query>). Dunno why they got rid of the simple count method.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has inbuilt method `count()` that can be called on cursor to find the number of documents returned.
I tried following piece of code in mongodb, that worked well, can be easily applied in java or any other language too:

`var findres = db.c.find()
 findres.count()` gave output `29353`